# $view->start(); and $view->finish(); in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

In following [Phalcon](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#stand-alone-component) code what do `start()` and `finish()` functions do?
It seems they could be embedded in `render()`

```
$view->start();
$view->render("products", "list");
$view->finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Phalcon manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html):

> public start ()
> Starts rendering process enabling the output buffering
>
> public finish ()
> Finishes the render process by stopping the output
> buffering

So it can not be embeded in the render.

Answer (score 0):

The start and finish calls are automatically done by Phalcon\Mvc\Application::handle, You can see an approximate behavior of this function in PHP [here](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/blob/master/simple-wapp/public/index.php)